# C# How to use Regex.split using &nbsp

Tags: c#

```
string Sample = "hello*&nbsp;*World"
Regex.Replace(Sample, "&nbsp", "-");
```

output should be:
hello-World

Somehow this code doesn't seem to work, please help I'm new at using regular expressions. Thanks :) (disregard the asterisk )

Comment: `&nbsp;` is an HTML entity, and doesn't make sense in a Regular Expression unless you want to match those characters literally. Can you give more information on where the input is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just use a regular space in this case like so

```
Regex.Replace(Sample, " ", "-");
```

but as this is rather simple you also just use `String.Replace` like so

```
Sample.Replace(" ", "-");
```